# HTML Modals is not pop uping

Tags: php, html, server, modal-dialog

I was building an application using PHP with the logic,

- opening two files.
- one file values to show the menus, echoing into the browser.
- if we click any menu, need to open a modal with a value containing the second file.

I just itrated with while loop.
The problem is...
menus from the first file are echoing. But, the modal is working only for the last menu.

When I inspect, the menus and modals are created.
https://postimg.cc/crQ8JCr5 - inspected screenshot

```
$myfile1 = fopen("fisrt-file.dat", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$myfile2 = fopen("Second-file.dat", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

while(!feof($myfile1)) {
    $fistFile = fgets($myfile1);
    $seconfFile = fgets($myfile2);
                      
    echo "<div class='one-by-three1'><div class='course-card1' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#".$seconfFile."'><p class='e-c-head'>".$fistFile."</p></div></div>";
                        
    echo "<div class='modal fade' id='".$seconfFile."' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalCenterTitle' aria-hidden='true'>
        <div class='modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered' role='document'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <h5 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLongTitle'>".$fistFile."</h5>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
                        <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-body'>
                              <p>Second file element</p>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-footer'>
                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
    }
fclose($myfile1);
fclose($myfile2);
```

I used bootstrap Modal.
Menus pass data-target as second file values.

Comment: From a UI perspective: You don't want to bash two modals to the user. You may consider using an accordion or one modal with a content switch. As far as I know, modals in bootstrap don't work the way you are expecting them to work.

Comment: @maio290 Thank you so much. I just did that using accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have changed to use accordion but was just about to tell you the reason it wasn't working so I will continue in case it helps somebody else.

The reason is because fgets reads the line *including* the new line character. So the ID's assigned to the modal are containing the new line character except for the last line which doesn't have the new line in the file so it works.

To make it work simply rtrim the line like so:

```
$fistFile = rtrim(fgets($myfile1));
$seconfFile = rtrim(fgets($myfile2));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. It's perfectly working with rtrim(). I made two choices with model and accordion. This is hat I am looking for. Once again thank you @Mark.